# Which kind of quote combination is preferred for MySQL queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, quotes

When inserting into MySQL with PHP, I can do either of the following:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO tablename SET id = "4"';
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename SET id = '4'";
$query = 'INSERT INTO tablename SET id = \'4\'';
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename SET id = \"4\"";
```

Is there a reason (security, performance, code readability, ...) why I should prefer one of them?

Comment: Whichever one you want.

Comment: You have a good answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: Whichever one you want, so long as you **PREPARE YOUR STATEMENTS**.

Comment: Personally, I always use the double quoted wrapped queries. There's less typing plus less room for error. *That's just me* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is the most common format:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename SET id = '4'";
```

So, you can easily come back and perform variable expansion like this:

```
$id = 4;
$table = "tablename";
$query = "INSERT INTO $table SET id = '$id'";
```

If the `4` is something passed in by the user, you would instead use parametrized queries and bind the parameter to avoid SQL injection:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$table = "tablename";
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablename SET id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on situation, in your case it should be:

`$query = 'INSERT INTO tablename (id) VALUES (4)';`

In case that you would want to insert an integer and a string, it should be:

`$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (id, name) VALUES (4, 'New York')";`

In case that you would want to build query by directly inserting variables into the query, it should be:

`$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (id, name) VALUES ($id, '$city')";`

- Building a query like this is prone to SQL injection.

In case that you would want to build query by using for example [PDO library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it would be:

`$query = 'INSERT INTO tablename (id, name) VALUES (:id, :city)';`

Comment: I'll reserve the downvote in case you don't correct the answer, but you **can** do `INSERT INTO ... SET col = ...`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Interesting, I have never ever seen such usage of `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Why would use single quotes on the first and last statements?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Because in case that I would use `""` then PHP interpreter would look for variables inside the string.

Comment: @MarcusAdams In case that I wrap string inside `""` and I don't use variables inside the string, then it is for readability purposes, `"Jake's mom"` is better readable then `'Jake\'s mom'`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Martin Bean mentioned, it would be a good idea to use prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename SET id=?");
$stmt->bind_param(4);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```